# Show groups/categories in MDS plots using SPSS

Tags: spss, mds

How can I edit my data or create a MDS plot in SPSS using PROXSCAL) in that I can add colors or different symbols for different categories? See example.(I don’t use a code line, but a menu commands in SPSS).

[image: MDS plot example]

I organized the data in lines and columns, added groups....